# Criar falso Relationship/Parentesco em model Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Eu tenho uma model pra minha tabela de postagens, ela fica mais ou menos assim:

```
$post = Post::where('titulo_url', $titulo_url)->first();
//$post->id
//$post->categoria_id
//$post->titulo_url
//$post->titulo
//$post->texto
```

Como devem ter imaginado, categoria_id é uma Relationship com outro model/tabela, a 'categorias'

```
class Post extends Model{
    public function categoria(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categoria');
    }
}
```

Através do `$post->categoria` posso retornar todos os dados da categoria, como `$post->categoria->nome`, por exemplo...

---

Eu também tenho a necessidade de ter o retorno de uma próxima postagem no meu post, consegui isso fazendo isso no controller:

```
$post = Post::where('titulo_url', $titulo_url)->first();
$post->proximo = DB::table('posts')->where('id', '>', $retorno->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->first();
```

Com isso, eu consigo através do `$post`, ter também retorno do próximo post... Assim:

```
$post->proximo->id;
$post->proximo->nome;
```

quase uma simulação de parentesco.

Como fazer diretamente dentro do model essa "Relationship" com a próxima postagem?

Answer (score 1):

Retornar uma instancia de `DB` não é a mesma coisa que uma instancia de `Post`. Pode parecer igual mas são coisas completamente diferentes.

Altere seu código para retornar uma instancia de `Post`:

```
$post = Post::where('titulo_url', $titulo_url)->first();
$proximoPost = Post::where('id', '>', $retorno->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->first();
```

Você poderia também extrair essa lógica do próximo `Post` para dentro do model:

```
class Post extends Model{
    public function categoria(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categoria');
    }

    public function nextPost(){
        // Aqui vem a lógica para retornar uma nova instancia do Post seguinte
        return $this->where('id', '>', $this->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->first();
    }
}
```

Nesse caso no seu controller:

```
$post->nextPost()->categoria->nome;
```